# Running Angular under Virtual Directory on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, iis-8

This question is related to Angular2+ (not AngularJS)

We are trying to host our angular site under a virtual directory under a website on IIS.

We have a Website Called Development that points to: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Development.`
In this folder we have another folder called `Web`. This Web folder holds the angular site code (built with `ng build --base-href "/Web" --deploy-url "/Web"`

When we navigate to http://server/Web, everything seems to be loading fine, except for the 0.chuck.js file. For some reason this file is being requested as:

`http://server/Web0.chuck.js`[image]

It seems like the "/" is missing before the 0, but I'm not sure where this setting could be handled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The url change is handled by webpack. This is controlled by the --deploy-url.

Running the following fixes it:

```
ng build --base-href "/Web" --deploy-url "/Web/"
```

Comment: Yes, this will work for all versions of angular2+ (we were actually on angular 4 when I created the question, I'll update the question to reflect) - unless a new version of angular uses a different cli. See this link for more information on ng build (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build). Basically this ng build comes down to how the index.html file is stitched up with the provided params.